# Why do I need to implement MyTrait<T> instead of MyTrait<TypeA> and MyTrait<TypeB>?

Tags: generics, rust

I coded a simple state machine:

```rust
struct Response {}

struct PlayResponse(Response);
struct DescribeResponse(Response);
struct EventError;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub(crate) struct RtspMachine {
    state: RtspState,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum RtspState {
    Init,
    Ready,
}

trait OnEvent<T> {
    fn on_event(
        &mut self,
        event: &T,
        rtsp_machine: &mut RtspMachine,
    ) -> std::result::Result<Self, ()>
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

impl OnEvent<PlayResponse> for RtspState {
    fn on_event(
        &mut self,
        event: &PlayResponse,
        rtsp_machine: &mut RtspMachine,
    ) -> std::result::Result<Self, ()> {
        match self {
            RtspState::Init => Ok(RtspState::Ready),
            RtspState::Ready => Ok(RtspState::Ready),
        }
    }
}

impl OnEvent<DescribeResponse> for RtspState {
    fn on_event(
        &mut self,
        event: &DescribeResponse,
        rtsp_machine: &mut RtspMachine,
    ) -> std::result::Result<Self, ()> {
        match self {
            RtspState::Init => Ok(RtspState::Ready),
            RtspState::Ready => Ok(RtspState::Ready),
        }
    }
}

impl RtspMachine {
    pub fn begin() -> RtspMachine {
        RtspMachine {
            state: RtspState::Init,
        }
    }

    fn event<T>(&mut self, event: &T) -> std::result::Result<(), EventError> {
        match self.state.on_event(event, self) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(()) => Err(EventError {}),
        }
    }
}
```

but I get

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `RtspState: OnEvent<T>` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:62:26
   |
62 |         match self.state.on_event(event, self) {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `OnEvent<T>` is not implemented for `RtspState`
```

I kinda understand why. I need to do a giant implementation:

```
impl OnEvent<T> for RtspState {
    fn on_event(
        &mut self,
        event: &T,
        rtsp_machine: &mut RtspMachine,
    ) -> std::result::Result<Self, ()> {
        match self {
            RtspState::Init => Ok(RtspState::Ready),
            RtspState::Ready => Ok(RtspState::Ready),
        }
    }
}
```

but that would make the implementation too big. I was happy to break it in different cases of `T`. Why can I not do this in Rust? Is there another way?

If I remember correctly, I can implement things for specific types instead of for generic `T` in C++.

Comment: You can do that, you just have to restrict `T` so that for all `T` the body of `fn event(...)` is valid. Which you can't do with the way your types are structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because as your code currently stands, Rust does not know whether the call to `self.state.on_event` is valid for any type `T` that is indicated in the function signature `fn event<T>(&mut self, event: &T) -> std::result::Result<(), EventError>`. For all Rust knows, that type `T` could be anything, whereas `RtspState::on_event` only has implementations where that type `T` is either `PlayResponse` or `DescribeResponse`. In fact, the compiler is telling you this with the error message `` the trait bound `RtspState: OnEvent<T>` is not satisfied ``. You can indicate to Rust that the function `event` should only be valid where `RtspState::on_event` has a valid implementation for `T` by adding `where RtspState: OnEvent<T>` after your return type and before your opening brace:

```rust
fn event<T>(&mut self, event: &T) -> std::result::Result<(), EventError>
where
    RtspState: OnEvent<T>,
{
```

For the full code, you can visit [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d09dbd772c3405e2c1a77c56215caa8).

Edit: Note that the playground link will fail to compile, but for different reasons besides the generic error.

Comment: This explanation is correct, but the suggested fix doesn't work for multiple reasons. I would suggest just adding a note to that effect in lieu of a broken playground link (if OP wants help with those other problems, they should ask a new question).

Comment: @trentcl should my note look something like that?

Comment: That's fine. I upvoted already, just offering some friendly feedback :)

Comment: No, I appreciate the feedback, I'm new to StackOverflow.